# My if statement is not working, it always starts with 'user already exist' whenever i reload the page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<?php     
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","earhartdb");

    if(isset($_POST['reg'])){

        $FName = $_POST['txtFname'];
        $SName = $_POST['txtSname'];
        $LName = $_POST['txtLname'];
        $EMail = $_POST['txtEname'];
        $Username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
        $Pass = $_POST['txtPass'];
        $Conpass = $_POST['txtConpass'];
        $Gender = $_POST['gender']; 


        $sql_user = "SELECT * FROM userstb WHERE Username = '$Username'";
        $sql_email = "SELECT * FROM userstb WHERE EMail = '$EMail'";
        $res_user = mysqli_query($con, $sql_user) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $res_email = mysqli_query($con, $sql_email) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            if(mysqli_num_rows($res_user) > 0){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("User already exist") </script>';
            }

            elseif(mysqli_num_rows($res_email) > 0){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Email already exist") </script>';
            }

            else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `userstb` (`FirstName`, `SecondName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Gender`, `Username`, `Password`, `ConfirmPassword`)VALUES ('$FName','$SName','$LName','$EMail','$Gender','$Username','$Pass','$Conpass')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

                 echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("You are now registered") </script>';
                 exit();
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is your objective? For sure when you reload, the data will be submitted again. Please explain the flow of your systems.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers will resend post parameters on reload. Try opening the page on an incognito tab.

Another way you can debug your code is by echoing the $Username and $res_user. This will allow you to see what is triggering the if statement.

If you determine that the problem is with the SQL database itself, I recommend that you run the queries directly through SQL to compare the results. Tools such as phpMyAdmin allow you easily browse an SQL database.